# ASP.NET MVC does not add ModelError when invoking from unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, model-binding

I have a model item

```
public class EntryInputModel
{
    ...

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller action

```
public ActionResult Add([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] EntryInputModel newEntry)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var entry = Mapper.Map<EntryInputModel, Entry>(newEntry);

        repository.Add(entry);
        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = entry.Id });
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

When I create an `EntryInputModel` in a unit test, set the `Description` property to `null` and pass it to the action method, I still get `ModelState.IsValid == true`, even though I have debugged and verified that `newEntry.Description == null`.

**Why doesn't this work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because model binding doesn't take place when you invoke an action from a test. Model binding is the process of mapping posted form values to a type and pass it as a parameter to an action method.

Comment: So how do I test that my controller verifies the model state before saving to db?

Comment: From your unit test, call ModelState.AddModelError("dummy", "some error text") before executing the method under test.